# why digits not used sometimes if this function

Tags: python, function, passwords

i need help. I have function and this function generates a password based on what the user has entered, but when numbers need to be used, sometimes they are not added to the password, why can this be? Here is the code:

```
def generate_secure_password(length, include_digits, include_symbols, include_uppercase):
    characters = string.ascii_lowercase
    if include_digits == 1:
        characters += string.digits
    if include_symbols == 1:
        characters += string.punctuation
    if include_uppercase == 1:
        characters += string.ascii_uppercase

    password = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(length))

    return password


a = generate_secure_password(8, 1, 1, 1)
print(a)
```

i try another commands but it doesnt help

Comment: Guys how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> sometimes they are not added to the password

You are doing

```
password = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(length))
```

so you take character *randomly* `length` times, therefore (as long as `characters` contain at least 1 non-digit character) you might end with digitless `password`.

Comment: ah, but how can i fix this poblem?

Comment: @FOX grab characters at random from `string.digits`, then grab characters at random from `string.punctuation`, then grab characters at random from `string.ascii_uppercase` then concatenate them